# How to use ::first-letter on a inline elements

Tags: html, css

```
p{display:inline;...}
<p>Hello</p>
p::first-letter{color: red;}
```

I want to use ::first-letter on that p.But it's a inline element, accroding to W3C, it doesn't work.
How to do?

Comment: Why would you make a `p` display inline in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

The `:first-letter` as defined in the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter only applies to a **block** element.

If you want you could use `display:inline-block` to make it work. Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/fZGFH/1/

Answer (score 2):

you can give `display:inline-block;`  to your **p** tag

Using the css display:block; and display:inline;, we can change the property of the element from block to inline or from inline to block as well....

Here is the code how you can do that

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>

  p {
      background:red;
      display:inline-block;
  }

p:first-letter
{
color:black;
    font-size:50px;


}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>CSS, short for Cascading Style Sheets, is a language used to control the presentation of HTML and XML documents. A basic CSS document is made out of rule sets. Each rule set starts with a selector, a pattern that matches elements in an HTML or XML document. The selector is followed by a block of ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

demo:- http://jsbin.com/eponir/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is the style for inline and first-letter case:

```
p{display:inline-block;}
p:first-letter {color:red}
```